# render a html helper if condition is true in razor view

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am rendering a html display helper  if condition is true but when i debuged the code condition is true but html helper is not rendering .

code

```
        <td> 
        @if(item.securityGate==true)
        {
      @Html.Display("securityGate")
        }
        </td>
```

i am checking condtion in column of a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@if(item.securityGate){
       Html.Display("securityGate")

   }
```

hope this will help you.